# Uploading to a Django DataBase from a template

Tags: html, django, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a webpage where you can upload questions to the `Questions` database. I was wondering is there any easy way to do this in Django? Can I upload it so it will be accessible from the Django admin? Here is what I have.

```
#Models
class Question(models.Model):
question = models.CharField(max_length=400)
answer = models.CharField(max_length=400)
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.question + "?"

class QuestionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['question', 'answer']

#Question Template
<div class="container" align="center">
  <div class="hero-unit3" align="center">
      <h3>
        Feel free to post some questions, and a DarKnight representative will answer them for you.
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6">
    <h4>
      <form action="<!-- NO IDEA WHAT TO DO -->" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="question" />
  </div>
</div>
</div>

#views.py
class question(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'users/question.html'
    context_object_name = 'Question_list'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.order_by('question')
```

Comment: @HieuNguyen added my views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve what you need is to use [CreateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview).

In views.py:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from yourapp.models import Question

class QuestionCreate(CreateView):
    model = Question
    fields = ['question', 'answer']
```

Create a new template name `question_form.html`:

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you! Helped out exactly as I needed.

Answer (score 0):

To make a model available to django admin you have to register the model to admin by

```
from django.contrib import admin

class Question(models.Model):
...

admin.site.register(Question)
```

Also for doing this from custom template you can use a [model form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)

The form can be displayed in the template as a table or as a paragraph.

Suppose you render the form to the template as `f`, use it in template as follows

```
<form action='..' method='post'>
{{ f.as_t }} //or f.as_p for paragraph
</form>
```

Comment: This helped out. I already know how to make it available in the admin. But is there a simple way to make it so I can post whatever I type in into the database? Also, is there a simpler way to create and import a `model form` into my Question template?